# WordPress menu how to add a class to only the parent a element?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, parent, nav

I want to add the class dropdown to only the parent  element. I tried to add some code to functions.php but that didn't solve my problem. Is it possible to do this with jquery/js?

```
<nav class="container_menu">
    <ul class="reset">
        <li class="active "><a title="Home" href="/" class="class here">Home</a></li>

        <li class="menu "><a title="parent" href="/parent" class="class here">parent</a>
            <ul class="reset">
                <li class=""><a title="child1" href="/child/child1">child 1</a></li>
                <li class=""><a title=child2" href="/child/child2">Child 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you're adding the menu from WP back-end you can set Parent-Child hierarchical menu. When you get menu in header.php you will get your desire structure with dropdown class as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `nav_menu_link_attributes` filter to modify the `<a>` attributes.

For your case, you can use the following code:

```
function add_classname_to_parent_nav_link($atts, $item) {

    // add class only on parent
    if($item->menu_item_parent == 0) {
        $atts['class'] = 'your-class-name';
    }   
    return $atts;   
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_classname_to_parent_nav_link', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using jquery or javascript or other framework client-side.

You can create a function and add filter to wp_nav_menu_objects, like this:

```
/**
* Add a parent CSS class for nav menu items.
*
* @param array  $items The menu items, sorted by each menu item's menu order.
* @return array (maybe) modified parent CSS class.
*/
function wpdocs_add_menu_parent_class( $items ) {
    $parents = array();

    // Collect menu items with parents.
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( $item->menu_item_parent && $item->menu_item_parent > 0 ) {
            $parents[] = $item->menu_item_parent;
        }
    }

    // Add class.
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( in_array( $item->ID, $parents ) ) {
            $item->classes[] = 'dropdown'; //here attach the class
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpdocs_add_menu_parent_class' );
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply! Sadly this adds a class to only the li element and not the a. Do you know a way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to achieve what you want. This adds the class "someclass" to any "li"-Element that contains an "ul"-Element within your given structure.

```
var menu = document.querySelector('nav.container_menu > ul');
  menu.childNodes.forEach((node,idx)=>{
    // find child-nodes of the ul 
    if(node.tagName == 'LI'){
      var hasSubMenu = false;
      node.childNodes.forEach( (subnode,idx)=>{
        if(subnode.tagName == 'UL'){
          hasSubMenu = true;
        }
      });
      if(hasSubMenu){
        node.classList+=" someclass";
      }
    }
  });
```

However, as you are working with wordpress, I suggest you do it the way you are supposed to create menus, i.E. with Walker_Nav_Menu / Walker_Page (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Page ) and wp_nav_menu() (see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/ ).

After a quick search I think this pretty much explains it detailed enough:

https://www.ibenic.com/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-menu-walker-nav-menu-class/